# Streaming of mp3 files

Tags: python, windows-7, streaming, mp3

I need a lightweight module that can stream a mp3 file from an HTTP server, play it on speakers, and allow seeking.

I'll write the GUI part, I just need a very simple backend to do something like this:

```
obj = MediaSource(r'http://myserver.com/my_song.mp3')
obj.play()
obj.seek(30)
```

Comment: Depending on which GUI library you use, it may already include support for this. e.g. wxPython's [`wx.media.MediaCtrl`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.media.MediaCtrl-class.html) allows you to embed Windows Media Player, including streaming and seeking support.

Comment: @Aya I'm using PyQt4, which ships with Phonon backends, but has known problems on Windows 7. That's why I'm looking for something else.

Comment: It's probably overkill in this case, but I've had very good results with the [Python bindings for libvlc](http://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings). [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) is another commonly-suggested option, but I've never tried it myself.

Comment: Yeah, I won't ship VLC with my program just for streaming audio... Also looked into pyglet, but it seems that it won't support streaming from Web.

Comment: Well, you might be able to hook into WMP's library somehow with the ctypes module. Anything useful [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio)?